# Apache mod_substitute json response body

Tags: apache

I am using apache mod_substitute module to alter my json response body . But it doesn't seem to be working

AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json

Substitute s|abc-docs|xyz-docs|ni

I have used the above code to perform the same . My json response would contain abc-docs as a value for a key called url ex : {"url":"abc-docs"}

I was expecting the response to contain {"url":"xyz-docs"} once it reaches the client .

Please advise

Comment: This works . Added the Substitute directive under a Location tag specific to the reverse proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works . Added the Substitute directive under a Location tag specific to the reverse proxy