# mod_substitute JSON Replace URL

Tags: json, apache, module, proxy

referring to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500106/apache-mod-substitute-json-response-body) Question:

UseCase: I POST a Request which I alter by ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse zu reach the Backend Server. The Response consits of Content-Type application/json, which contians a Backend URL that I have to Replace manually.

My Config File (proxy-https.conf) is included by the httpd.conf and usually working ok (e.g. ProxyPass  is working fine). Setup is like:

```
Listen 443     
  <VirtualHost *:443>

  my rules...

</VirtualHost>
```

My approach was to use mod_substitute to replace the URL in the json. But i cannot get it to replace the backend URL no matter what I did:

```
Substitute "s|backend-server:2719|proxy-host:443|ni"
```

Or:

```
<Location "/">
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
    Substitute "s|backend-server:2719|proxy-host|ni"
</Location>
```

And: I have to add the modlule AGAIN, though it was already add in the httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
```

Is there a a general error in my apporach or can I do it another way? Maybe another modult?

Tanks!

Answer (score 3):

OK, found the answer myself:

```
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

FilterDeclare FnRofSGWinJSON
FilterProvider FnRofSGWinJSON SUBSTITUTE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/json|"

FilterDeclare unpackGZIP
FilterProvider unpackGZIP INFLATE "resp('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip'"

<Location "/my/pressous/path/">
  FilterChain unpackGZIP FnRofSGWinJSON DEFLATE
  Substitute "s|${URL_1}|${URL_2}/MarkerPath|in"
</Location>
```

Open is, why I have to load the modules again...